# Cannot get circle to cut around image!

Tags: inkscape, svg

[image]

Trying to make a logo similar to this in Inkscape but cannot get the parts of the circle to cut out around the image. I've tried everything. Difference, intersection, Object-Set-Cut. Nothing works. The image I am using in place of the bicycle is also ungrounded.

Comment: There's a spelling error in the logo. The word "cycling" has no K in it.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do it. Here are some:

One method is to copy and paste several circles in place, then edit the start and end points of the arcs.

For example

[image]

Another method is to use a clipping path.  First create a shape on top of the circle, then select both circle and shape, and do *Object > Clip > Set*

[image]

Another is to give your text/artwork a thick outer white stroke so that it hides parts of the circle behind the stroke.

For example

[image]